# Implement security in webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have asp.net Web services, and I use them in my site using JS ajax calls.
I would like to set up a security mechanism (of any type) that will allow only users surfing the site to call them, and not just anyone requesting from those webservices.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Building Secure Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648643.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A simple way will be to know the IP address of your site and then check whether its same as

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

Allow access only if both matches.

Comment: but this is the client's IP. what does it have to do with my site's IP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ASP.NET Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx).For more on authentication in webservirce check [this](http://progtutorials.tripod.com/Authen.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented security to my Webservices with [Web Service Enhancements 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14089). There are many basic examples on the net that you can check out. But basically you want every Method to be called through a `Post` instead of  a `Get`, and you would send a `SOAPHeader` with every HTTP call. The service/method checks the `SOAPHeader` validates and returns valid content only if the user is authenticated/valid.

Good luck!